# printing incremental differences between pandas columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi this is quite simple but I was wondering if anyone knew how to print the differences between two columns. I currently have this:

```
    end | begin
    935    916
    961    916
    972    916
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
    end | begin | diff
    935    916     916,917,918,919,920...935
    961    916     916,917,918...961
    972    916     916,917,918...972
```

Does anyone know a simple column operation that could generate this? Currently the code i have is:

```
timestamp = []
for x in range(len(listdates)):
    while start_date <= listdates[x]:
        timestamp.append(str(start_date)+'|')
        start_date+=1
start_date = 916
```

timestamp = ''.join(timestamp)

However this code is quite tedious and does not provide the correct output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for process by rows and then lambda function with `range`:

```
print (df)
   end  begin
0  920    916
1  961    916
2  972    916

df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: range(x['begin'], x['end'] + 1), axis=1)
print (df)
  end  begin                                               diff
0  920    916                          (916, 917, 918, 919, 920)
1  961    916  (916, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921, 922, 923, 924, ...
2  972    916  (916, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921, 922, 923, 924, ...
```

And if need `string`s is posssible convert each `int` value created by `range` or better use [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), convert to `str` and list and use `join`:

```
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(np.arange(x['begin'], x['end']+ 1)
                                           .astype(str).tolist()), axis=1)
print (df)
   end  begin                                               diff
0  920    916                                916,917,918,919,920
1  961    916  916,917,918,919,920,921,922,923,924,925,926,92...
2  972    916  916,917,918,919,920,921,922,923,924,925,926,92...
```

Comment: Fascinating. Thank you for your response! Curious however, why did you prefer to use numpy.arange?

Comment: because range create list of ints and it is a bit complicated for convert to str - need list comprehension.